# Apache server working, PHP isn't

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I had a php tool working on my old macbook pro. I've recently install via homebrew the HTTPD server and install PHP per a few websites.

The local page loads but it seems that PHP isn't working properly. When trying to use the following, nothing shows up

[PHPinfo error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiQrp.png)

There may be more errors with my new OSX Ventura with PHP 8.2 that I didn't have before, but nothing in the error_log's shows anything.

I'm a bit outside of my realm on this one, could use some help.  Pretty much googled all that I could. Thank you

Comment: seems apache doesn't know it should send php file requests to php

Comment: Can you add your Apache configuration file?

Comment: I followed this guide..  except I only used php8.2

https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-ventura-apache-multiple-php-versions

Will upload my conf now

Comment: @eKKiM

Here is the httpd.conf file

https://files.fm/u/kh8zwygny

Only thing I added was the mod_rewrite and the libphp and directory/username

Thought it was pretty standard guideline to follow but I've clear missing something.

Comment: ) -> which php
/usr/local/bin/php


() -> php -v
PHP 8.2.5 (cli) (built: Apr 12 2023 11:59:18) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.5, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.2.5, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Comment: I've just closed this down and installex XAMP.  Works well